# Entity framework Unidirectional Association One to Many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I'm new in Entity Framework and my English is not very good, sorry if i write something wrong. I want to make an unidirectional association in One-to-Many relationship with Entity Framework 6 using the following example:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int personId;
    public string Name;
    .
    .
    .
    //public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; } //I don't want this nav property

}

public class Phone 
{
    public int phoneId;
    public string number;

    public Person myPerson { get; set; }
}
```

In this classes, a Person has many Phone, so a Phone has only a Person (1 to 1...*) but I want to create the navigation property in Phone, not in Person.

How to create this association with Fluent API for mappings?

Answer (score 4):

Use following mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>().HasRequired(p => p.myPerson).WithMany();
```

- [HasRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671317%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) configures required relationship for phone (i.e. it's required to have person id)
- [WithMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696499%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) configures relationship to be required:many without navigation property on *many* side

Consider reading [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, but I want to complicated a little more the model

    public class Person 
    {
    public int personId;
    public string Name;
    }

    public abstract class Phone {
    public int phoneId;
    .

    public int personId;
    }

    public class PhoneFixedLine : Phone {
    .
    public Person myPerson { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhoneCellPhone : Phone {
    .
    public Person myPerson { get; set; }
    }

So far I know the Navigation properties are no inherited, that's why I added them in child classes, How can i make the relationship wight now?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to be more clear on what you want, considering you changed your question in Sergey's answer.

Considering it, this is what your classes will look like (yes, navigation properties inheritance is supported):

```
public class Person 
{ 
   public int personId { get; set; } 
   public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class Phone 
{ 
   public int phoneId { get; set; } 
   public int personId { get; set; } 
   public Person myPerson { get; set; } 
}

public class PhoneFixedLine : Phone 
{  } 
public class PhoneCellPhone : Phone 
{  }
```

Obs.: Mind the *getters* and *setters* in the `Person` and `Phone` classes.

You want an unidirectional mapping with the navigation property in the `Phone` class.

Since you are mapping derivated classes you need to follow an *Inheritance Strategy*, see [this link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)for more information.

I will be following the TPC strategy where only the concrete classes are mapped.

In the `OnModelCreatingMethod` do the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PhoneFixedLine>().HasRequired(p => p.myPerson).WithMany()
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("FixedPhones");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PhoneCellPhones>().HasRequired(p => p.myPerson).WithMany()
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("CellPhones");
        });            
    }
```

You will face an identity problem with this strategy because these two table share the same primary key `phoneId`, in the link of the Inheritance Strategies there are two ways of dealing with it.